# Any suggestions and recommendations for mapping long straight corridors using gmapping?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, gmapping-demo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to map a long straight corridor using turtlebot gmapping demo on actual robot. For a short segment of the run the robot maps the corridors nicely giving straight edges but as the distance increases, i find it hard to map the environment correctly. Either it curves out the corridor or it branch out another map out on the rviz suggesting it is not able to localize properly. I get parallel maps where the corridor branches out from the main map.

Any suggestions into improving the map? What settings are recommended. My turtlebot is properly calibrated , i know there are imu errors and odometry errors involved but how to improve on it? Does changing the topic to `/odom` provide better results?

I am using ROS fuerte with kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46996/any-suggestions-and-recommendations-for-mapping-long-straight-corridors-using-gmapping?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The mapping problem has troubled robots for years now... The corridor is not a good place to map. The more landmarks present in an environment, the more accurate the map can be. You may have noticed that the results are never consistent in mapping. There are always small differences.

From my experiences with the turtlebot, the best way to improve mapping is:

1. increase the number of particles used
2. increase the update speed

That's about all one can do for the robot...

Best of luck,

-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-29**:
I would also try to play around with the odometry weight parameters. I'm sure they are not optimal and at least some performance improvement could be achieved.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-10-29**:
yes - I think the gyro is most optimal around 2.36 (If memory serves me). Try setting it to 2.40 and see what the odometry calibration says to adjust it to.

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-29**:
I have a 250 deg/sec gyro. On calibration for 5-6 times the values were near 1.5 .. I will check if the 2.40 value makes any difference , thanks for the info..